# What goes in your root component

Tags: angular

I am using the angular CLI and I have generated a new project. What would normally go in your app.component.ts?

I haven't found a use for it yet as everything else sits in its own module/component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.component.ts typically acts like a root component of your application. Where you place the **router-outlet**, headers, footers and router-outlet is the one which holds the views based on your routing.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

For more info: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: That's currently what I am using it for. So in a way its for layout logic?

Comment: It is for the basic "shell" for your application. Everything else you build will run within that "shell". For best performance, it is normally recommended that you keep your app.component piece as simple as possible so it can be downloaded quickly for a fast display of the shell of your application.

Answer (score 0):

A typical example for `app.component.html` would be a layout template and the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` element. The app-root should be considered the main entry point of you app, so basically you put what you want to see **across the entire app**.

On the other hand, inside of `app.component.ts` should be code that will be executed **only once** during the app execution. Configuration of services, register custom icons in the material icon service, configuration of global variables, etc. Basically **configuration stuff** or **code that should be executed once**.